# How can add line color in left recyclerview

Tags: android

I try to add line color in left recyclerview as the image for example

[image]

How I can add same it ?

Comment: Did you try to add a `View` within layout? And post your xml also in your question.

Comment: It worked with (View ) now .Thank you, brother

Answer (score 0):

```
DividerItemDecoration divider = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
divider.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getBaseContext(), R.drawable.my_divider));
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider);
```

and in my_divider.xml file sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/blue" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Hi brother.. This code comes in color from the bottom of line. I need it to be in left line and inside (CardView or  recyclerview )